# Spring 3.0 File Upload

Tags: spring, servlets

Can anyone spot why the file (Http.Part) Variable is null after submitting the form?

Controller Code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addImage(Account account, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, 
        Locale locale,HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) Part file){

        if(file==null){
            uiModel.addAttribute("file_error", "File upload failure");

        }
```

View

```
 <spring:url value="/account/update" var="update" />
<form:form modelAttribute="account" action="${update}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
<c:if test="${file_error != null}">
Errors: ${file_error }
</c:if><br />
<label for="file">
    <spring:message code="account.upload.file"/>
</label>
        <input name="file" type="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" /> 
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add a `multipartResolver`?

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 
   <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have this:<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"
        id="multipartResolver"/>